# Plotting Johannesburg Stock Exchange Data to Quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I import JSE stock data from Google into R using `quantmod` with the following code:

```
library("quantmod")
getSymbols("JSE:BIL",src='google')
```

It imports fine but as soon as I plot it,

```
barChart(JSE:BIL)
```

I get the following error

> Error in do.call("chartSeries", list(x, subset = subset, name = name,  : 
>   object 'JSE' not found

Guess it is the colon...
Any workarounds? Could I rename the xts object?

Thank you
Fanie

Answer (score 0):

When you place a cursor inside the brackets, it will suggest a list if you have more than one input. Just click the relevant one and it will output as below.

```
barChart(`JSE:BIL`)
```

or use `JSE:BIL`